# Hide column in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Imagine that i have the structure below:

```
      $scope.gridOptions = {
                enableHorizontalScrollbar: 1,
                enableFiltering: true,
                paginationPageSizes: [150, 300, 450],
                paginationPageSize: 150,
                rowHeight: 110,
                data: data,
                columnDefs: [
{  name: 'IdQuestion', field: 'IdQuestion', displayName: 'Question Number' , enableCellEdit: false  , width :'60' },         
{  name: 'Category', field: 'Category', displayName: 'Category' , enableCellEdit: false  , width :'83'  }
```

I need to create a button in order to hide the Category column, i was thinking that this would work :/

```
 $("#gridOptions").field("Category").hide();
```

but it didn't , can you guys let me know the correct way to access to the category column.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're mixing jQuery and angular here. Usually you can do such a thing completely from within angular using 'ng-hide' or 'ng-show' directives. Use your button to toggle the bound value on these maybe?

Comment: thanks Gunter, I'm looking for a good example for such thing, do you have any one ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<label ng-show="gridOptions[0].enableCellEdit">Category</label>
```

in the above code if enableCellEdit is true then that label will show other wise it will hide.

Comment: thanks thigala , how can i add it into the column definition , will this work : 
 name: 'Category', field: 'Category', displayName: 'Category' , enableCellEdit: false  , width :'83', ng-show: "gridOptions[0].enableCellEdit"  }